# Three.js texture loading fail

Tags: 3d, three.js, textures, render

I am working to an animation with three.js I am triyng to rotate 2 spheres at the center of the screen, the firstone contains the second one (they have the same coords but one i a little bigger). I am trying to simulate a realistic earth globe with atmosphere.

I started with the three.js earth globe example adding the atmosphere http://www.gioblu.com/GiO/web/solarsystem/index_old

After that i wrote everything from scratch to have a framework to render many planets, and their atmospheres..

http://www.gioblu.com/GiO/web/solarsystem/index_backup
But, as you can see, there is a bug in my code that avoid the correct texture loading. 
Looking inside material object, seems all to be there inside. I think I am adding the items in the scene before the texture is loaded. But i can't find a way to edit the code to let it work..

I hope in a good answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You create the MeshPhongMaterial when the texture has finished loading. Before the texture is loaded, however, the mesh has already been created. Since this.atmosphere_material is still undefined, basic material is used.

In your loader function you've got a scoping error which might cause this problem:

```
      this.loader.load( 'app/textures/atmospheres/earth_1.jpg', function ( texture ) {
        this.atmosphere_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          map: texture,
          color: 10790052,
          ambient: 16777215,
          emissive: 1381653,
          specular: 16777215,
          shininess: 5000,
          opacity: 0.46,
          transparent: true,
          wireframe: false
        });
      });
```

The this.atmosphere_material property isn't set on the Earth object. In this callback the scope is different. The following is an easier way to load textures:

```
var Earth = function() {

      this.planet = new THREE.Object3D();
      this.planet_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 32, 32 );

      this.atmosphere = new THREE.Object3D();
      this.atmosphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 205, 32, 32 );

      this.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "app/textures/surfaces/earth.jpg" ),
          color: 13750737,
          ambient: 13092807,
          emissive: 595494,
          specular: 3223857,
          shininess: 25,
          opacity: 1,
          transparent: false,
          wireframe: false,
      });

      this.surface = new THREE.Mesh( this.planet_geometry, this.material );
      this.planet.add(this.surface);
      scene.add( this.planet );


      this.atmosphere_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "app/textures/atmospheres/earth_1.jpg" ),
          color: 10790052,
          ambient: 16777215,
          emissive: 1381653,
          specular: 16777215,
          shininess: 5000,
          opacity: 0.46,
          transparent: true,
          wireframe: false
        });

      this.surface = new THREE.Mesh( this.atmosphere_geometry, this.atmosphere_material );
      this.atmosphere.add(this.surface);
      scene.add( this.atmosphere );
    }
```

I haven't tested the code, but should be correct.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you mean the overlapping texture, wireframe you see?